# Scrape full contents of web page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to build a Shiny app to track vaccine progress, since the [CDC page](https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations) doesn't retain historical information. Looking at the page code with Chrome DevTools, I can see that I want to pull information from every `<div>` tag with class `"card-content"`, which I tried doing with the following code, using the `rvest` package:

```
data <- read_html('https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations')
current_numbers <- data %>% html_nodes('div.card-content')
```

This returns an empty object with structure "List of 0."

I also used `readr::read_file` to generate a .txt file to see if something weird was happening. It returned a file with

```
    <main id="maincontent">

    </main>
```

and no intervening content, though the header and footer code seems all there.

Is there a better way to pull the data from the `<main>` content on the page? Is `rvest` the right package for this? I alternatively could try `bs4` in Python, but don't know how to make a Shiny app from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website is dealing with dynamic content, so you wont get any information that way.

I am not that deep in `r`, but as you mentioned `python` and `bs4` I could give you an small an working example.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations"

driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

driver.close()
[{'title': item.find('h4').get_text(), 'value': item.find('div').get_text()}  for item in soup.select('div.card-content')]
```

**Output**

```
[{'title': 'Total Doses Distributed', 'value': '37.960.000'},
 {'title': 'Total Doses Administered', 'value': '17.546.374'},
 {'title': 'Number of People Receiving 1 or More Doses',
  'value': '15.053.257'},
 {'title': 'Number of People Receiving 2 Doses', 'value': '2.394.961'},
 {'title': 'Doses Administered in Long-Term Care Facilities ',
  'value': '2.089.181'}]
```